# Eclipse rcp databinding with array of values

Tags: data-binding, eclipse-rcp, preferences

I have read [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseDataBinding/article.html) and I am familiar with simple databinding.

But how do I handle databinding with arrays of values?

For example I want to make a Preferences page for my app where I need to set multiple values for multiple possible profiles, which can be added or removed.

Similar thing that I want to do is an Eclipse Preferences page General->Keys, where you can select Schemes and set values for that scheme. What I need to do additionally is to be able to add and remove schemes.

thank you in advance for any tips, example and links.

regards

Comment: would be helpful if you could post a snippet of your datamodel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use observable collections, like [in this example](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseDataBinding/ar01s04.html).